# How to choose embedded library over installed library?

Tags: xcode, macos

My application embeds several binary libraries (.dylib), which are located in the `Contents/Frameworks` folder.
However, when I execute the application tries to load already installed library versions over my embedded version.

How can I tell my application to use the embedded version? I am sure it must be simple but I wasn't able to find the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Zelyin, thanks again, but the problem isn't solved.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your project and click build phase section and extend Embed Frameworks section after change the **Copy only when installing** as ss below

[image]

Comment: thank you! Unfortunately, it wasn't set before. Interestingly, this section is called "Embed Libraries" in my Xcode. But still it wants to place them to Destination "Frameworks". Is that an issue?